# Where to put twisted-theseus profiler?

Tags: python, profiling, twisted

I am trying to add [twisted-theseus](https://github.com/flowroute/twisted-theseus) profiler to my twisted app.

I run app as following:

```
/bin/twistd my_app
```

I putted lines just after app entrypoint:

```
t = Tracer()
t.install() 
with open('callgrind.theseus', 'wb') as outfile:
    t.write_data(outfile)
```

Everything that I see in output `callgrind.theseus` file is:

> events: Nanoseconds

What I do wrong?

Comment: What `outfile` should contains? What are you trying to save in the file?

Comment: The problem is you are installing the tracer and then immediately dumping the stats, so what you get  is expected. You can have two endpoints where one endpoint will install the tracer and other endpoint which will uninstall and dump the data to file. You can then call the endpoint using curl to activate profiling and the other endpoint to dump this data.